# XSLT: how to test for the existence of at least one qualified child node/@date

Tags: xslt, compare

I want to test for events within a group that qualify for both city and current-date() so that I can output a header.

To find the city ($place eq //event/@city) seems to work. But I can't figure out how to express "some eventTime/@date is less than $today". The error message is "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second operand of 'eq'" Which is confusing because I've written test="($place eq //event/@city) and (xs:date($today) lt xs:date(//eventTime/@date)).

How should I be comparing $today to the @date in my eventTime? Here's the input.

```
<calendar>  
<group month="2012-04-01">
    <event city="paris">
        <eventTime date="2012-04-02"/>
        <eventText>Paris - expired April date</eventText>
    </event>
    <event city="london">
        <eventTime date="2012-04-19"/>
        <eventText>London - current April 19 date</eventText>
    </event>
    <event city="london">
        <eventTime date="2012-04-24"/>
        <eventText>London - current April date</eventText>
    </event>
</group>
<group month="2012-05-01">
    <event city="london">
        <eventTime date="2012-05-02"/>
        <eventText>London - current May date</eventText>
    </event>
    <event city="paris">
        <eventTime date="2012-05-01"/>
        <eventText>Paris - current May date</eventText>
    </event>
    <event city="london">
        <eventTime date="2012-05-02"/>
        <eventText>London - current May date</eventText>
    </event>
</group>

</calendar>
```

Here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://johnadamturnbull.com/xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0" >

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

    <xsl:param name="place" as="xs:string" required="yes"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="today" select="current-date()" as="xs:date"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
           <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="calendar/group"/>
        </body>
        </html>  
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match = "group">

        <xsl:if test="($place eq //event/@city) and
               (xs:date($today) ge xs:date(//eventTime/@date))">

              <h4 class = "dateHeader">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(./@month,'[MNn] [Y]')"/>
                </h4>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="event"></xsl:apply-templates>
                </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="event">
       <xsl:variable name="eventTime" select="eventTime/@date" as="xs:date"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($eventTime ge $today) and
                            (($place eq @city) or (@city eq ''))">
                <li>
                        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
                </li>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `//event/@city` is returning a sequence of 6 items. Can you post your XSLT so we can see what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I said "less than today" -- I meant >= today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an example of what the HTML output is supposed to be, but I'm pretty sure I can tell what you're trying to achieve.

I think your XSLT can be simplified by removing the `xsl:if` and `xsl:choose` and adding predicates to do your testing.

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:fn="http://johnadamturnbull.com/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="place" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="today" select="current-date()" as="xs:date"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="calendar/group"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Match group if @city matches $place or is empty and has an eventTime
  with a @date that is greater than or equal to today's date.-->
  <xsl:template match="group[event[@city=$place or @city=''][xs:date(eventTime/@date) >= $today]]">
      <h4 class="dateHeader">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(@month,'[MNn] [Y]')"/>
      </h4>
      <ul>
        <!--Only apply-templates to events that have a @city that matches $place
        or has a @city that is empty.-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="event[@city=$place or @city='']"/>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Only match events that have an eventTime with a @date that is greater than 
  or equal to today's date.-->
  <xsl:template match="event[@city=$place or @city=''][xs:date(eventTime/@date) >= $today]">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="event"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example XML input produces this HTML output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h4 class="dateHeader">April 2012</h4>
      <ul>
         <li>London - current April 19 date</li>
         <li>London - current April date</li>
      </ul>
      <h4 class="dateHeader">May 2012</h4>
      <ul>
         <li>London - current May date</li>
         <li>London - current May date</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, please add an example of what the HTML output should look like.

Comment: That's exactly the output I need. It works fine for "London". But when I pass in the place parameter "Paris", it fails. (The result I get is ... <body>Paris - expired April date
      <li>London - current April 19 date</li>

Comment: @JohnTurnbull - Sorry about that. I needed to add the $place predicate on the event match and I needed to add another event match to catch the strays. Please see my edit.

Comment: This is terrific! I'm getting predicates now. Thank you so much -- this is really useful.

Comment: I was about to abandon the XSLT and do this in XQuery. You also write XQuery; would you have used it in instead?

Comment: @JohnTurnbull - You're very welcome. No I'd still do this in XSLT, but I'm also more comfortable in XSLT. The key here is knowing how to use XPath. If I did do this in XQuery, I'd probably still use the same XPath (with the predicates).